# Web parts disappearing as soon as they are re-added to the page

Tags: web-part, error, 2003

Our SharePoint 2003 server went down last night. Its come back online after an IIS reset, but there are various web parts missing from our landing page. When I try to re-add these components they go missing again as soon as a single page refresh happens.

When I try to open the page in SharePoint designer 2007 I receive the following error:

> ```
> soap:Server Exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException was thrown.  The file is not available. Either the file does not exist or it cannot be edited from its current location.
> ```

How can I find what's happening here and resolve the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not in the IIS error logs, or the event logs this turned out to be the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823547

Putting here in the hopes I save somebody else the headaches of my morning!